# Comparing time and day with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

On my code I am trying to verify if an appointment cancellation request was issued at 1 hour before the appointment start_time. Here is the code I'm using but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    let status;
    const timeLimit = moment.utc(tappedItem.start_time, 'HH:mm:ss').subtract(1, 'hour')

    // checking is same date && after time limit
    if (item.date === moment.utc() && moment.utc().isAfter(timeLimit, "hour")) {
         return status = 0 // within 1 hour
    } else {
        status = 1 //
    }
```

I think there is something wrong with my first if clause. Does anyone know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What is `tappedItem`? `item.date`? Did you log out the values of each variable to see if it was what you expect?